# copy file to remote desktop drive

Tags: powershell, remote-desktop, file-copying

I want to copy a file from my local C:\filename.png to the remote computer to which I am connected via remote desktop's C:\ drive.

Is it possible to copy using powershell or anyother terminal command?

I am using windows 7 (local PC) --- Remote Desktop (Windows Server 2003)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your host's c: drive is injected into a terminal services session, it just gets a new drive letter in the remote session.

On my network, my host machine's drives are injected into a VM and C: becomes M:.

So in that case, in the remote session:

**copy c:\file.png m:\png**

BUt perhaps a beter way - from your host:

**Copy \\remote\c$\file.png c:\file.png**

Answer (score 4):

My remote session usually names the local resource `tsclient`, such that I can browse my local C drive with this PS command:

```
Set-Location \\tsclient\C
```

then I can do anything I would normally do on the local file system, e.g. copying:

```
copy \\tsclient\C\file.txt C:\file.txt
```

Comment: How do you determine the remote session name?
In my case that name is not correct, but I am curious how I would locate that name, assuming it exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can share a folder on your server and map it as network drive on the client computer. Then you can use the copy command.

At the server side you kann check and deplace the files manually or with a program.

Answer (score -1):

> if both are Windows 7 ;
>    Just copy and paste done in ordinary window

Answer (score -1):

If both machines run the same OS, then it can be achieved

If you are using mstc program then
Go to Remote Desktop Connection -> Options -> Local Resources -> check the drivers option and connect to the remote PC. Then you can perform copy paste like usual