# Copy local text file to remote desktop

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net

I am trying to copy a **`local text file`** which is in my working directory to other **`remote desktop`**

This is the way I am trying to do as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527770/copy-file-to-remote-desktop-drive)

**`ExecuteCommand("Copy" & Directory.GetCurrentDirectory & "\Output\Files.txt \\myservername -u username -p password C$\Files.txt")`**

```
Public Sub ExecuteCommand(ByVal Command As String)
        Dim ProcessInfo As ProcessStartInfo
        Dim Process As Process
        ProcessInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/K" & Command)
        ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = True
        Process = Process.Start(ProcessInfo)
End Sub
```

I'm getting this error:

***`The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect`***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, you are missing a space after the "Copy":

```
ExecuteCommand("Copy" & Directory.GetCurrentDirectory & ...
```

that will turn into (given that the current directory is "C:\MYDIR" as an example)

```
cmd.exe /kCopyC:\MYDIR
```

The lack of a space after the `/k` option to `cmd.exe` is not a problem, but looks awkward. I'd put one there as well.

Second, the `"\\myservername -u username -p password C$\Files.txt"` looks just wrong. That should probably be `"\\myservername\C$\Files.txt"` following your example. Username and password makes no sense at this point and in the context of the `Copy` command (copy past error?).

Then you have some bogus(?) line wrappings in the "ExecuteCommand..." example of your question. Could be that those are causing more issues but this is hard to tell as it stands.

Output the value of the `Command` variable in your `ExecuteCommand` method (or use a debugger) and check if it is sound. Also, try to execute the whole thing from the command line first to make sure it works.

Putting it all together, I would have written it like this:

```
ExecuteCommand("Copy " & Directory.GetCurrentDirectory & "\Output\Files.txt \\myservername\C$\Files.txt")

' ...

Public Sub ExecuteCommand(ByVal Command As String)
        Dim ProcessInfo As ProcessStartInfo
        Dim Process As Process
        ProcessInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/K " & Command)
        ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = True
        Process = Process.Start(ProcessInfo)
        ' You might want to wait for the copy operation to actually finish.
        Process.WaitForExit()
        ' You might want to check the success of the operation looking at
        ' Process.ExitCode, which should be 0 when all is good (in this case).
        Process.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Finally, you could have just used [`File.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a.aspx) instead. No need to invoke `cmd.exe` for that:

```
File.Copy(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory & "\Output\Files.txt", 
   "\\myservername\C$\Files.txt")
```

Comment: @Christian.K- First thanks for your detailed explanation and If I use the above syntax File.Copy(...) It gives me and error stating that "Login Failure..Bad username or password" but able to open remote desktop using the same username and password.

Comment: You need to make sure that the user (ultimately running the `File.Copy` or your `ExecuteCommand`) actually has write-access to the destination (i.e. to `\\myservername\c$\`).

Comment: I am using file.copy and I have just now checked with that "C$"..It has full read and write and execute permissions too.